# How can we use conditional tags in plugins?

Tags: conditional-tags

In the plugin, The css file loads sitewide by default, I want to load it only on the Single post.

the conditional tags, i.e, is_single() isn’t working in plugins,

any idea how can we achieve that?

Comment: Can you share with us your code, like what did you try so far?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. So, basically there is a plugin called TablePress and its only used in single post so it doesn't make sense to load the css sitewide. I tried using this code http://pastebin.com/jLT0t8P6

but it didn't worked all the way through.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: This code checks whether on home page or not, you should be using [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) hook with [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) to add the CSS or `wp_head` for inline ones, and there use `if( ! is_single() ) return;` on top so as to avoid queuing the CSS while not needed.. What's confusing?

Answer (score 1):

**TL,DR;**

You are hooking early.

---

> In the plugin, the css file loads site-wide by default, I want to load
>   it only on the single post.

It's a very good thought many developers don't take this into account while developing themes/plugins.

> **`is_single()`** isn’t working in plugins

Where are you using **`is_single`** template tag in [WP run cycle](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) ?

## Assuming you are hooking to **`init`** or **`wp`**

Template tags are not available yet until **`template_redirect`** action. So those tags don't work for **`init`** or **`wp`**.

Best place to work with scripts or styles is on **`wp_enqueue_scripts`** which runs after **`template_redirect`** .

> Any idea how can we achieve that ?

There are many ways to achieve depending on the plugin we are using.

Coming to **TablePress** plugin.

`controllers/controller-frontend.php` is the place where plugin is en-queue-ing stylesheet.

```
if ( apply_filters( 'tablepress_use_default_css', true ) || TablePress::$model_options->get( 'use_custom_css' ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_css' ) );
}
```

You can completely turn off en-queuing the stylesheet using the **`tablepress_use_default_css`** and custom css option to false, and then load them wherever you need in your custom plugin/theme.

If you dig through the file there are many conditional en-queuing is done for that plugin.

You can also dequeue style first and then enqueue wherever needed.

## Sample code

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wp_228402_load_styles_conditionally',11);
function wp_228402_load_styles_conditionally() {
  if(is_single()){
    return; // return if not on the single post/page
  }
  wp_dequeue_style('tablepress-default'); 
}
```

Check the **priority** for the above that's the key it should be greater than  default value **10**.

Comment: For conditionals like is_single() then, how then do we tell our plugin "Wait until wp or init is loaded and then run all of this plugin's functions"?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this in your functions.php file:

```
if( is_single()) {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'ahmedkaludi-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/plugin-styles.css' );
}
```

Change '/css/plugin-styles.css' to the actual path of the plugin's stylesheet.

If the plugin is written well, `wp_enqueue_style` will be wrapped in a function, like:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_scripts' ) ) {
  function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ahmedkaludi-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/plugin-styles.css' );
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'steveclason_flat_scripts' );
}
```

If that's how it's done in the plugin you can override it with a similar block of code in your theme's functions.php. We can't make very good recommendations without seeing how the plugin calls the stylesheet -- the block of code on your Pastebin does something else.